# Is it possible to build an OTA update from two system images?

Tags: ota-update, side-loading

I am impatiently waiting for someone to capture the download link for the Android 6.0.1 OTA update for the Nexus 6 so that I can sideload it, but I've been wondering if it would be possible to build an OTA update by using the version of the ROM that I currently have installed on my phone and a copy of the new version. Can this be done, and if so, how? I have looked at the information on the Android Developer's Website, but I do not understand it at all.